# What do you call functions which get and set?

Tags: oop, accessor, nomenclature, mutators

The jQuery framework has a lot of functions which will either retrieve or mutate values depending on the parameters passed:

```
$(this).html();       // get the html
$(this).html('blah'); // set the html
```

Is there a standard name for functions which behave like this?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is no "standard" name for a single function that acts both as a getter and as a setter. It's an idiom not very commonly used, but it's possible in some languages, and as long as it's well documented, there's no harm in using it.

Comment: wouldn't it be possible in any language which allows either optional parameters (php, javascript, python, ruby ...), or function overloading (java...)?

Comment: Yes, as long as these languages have a way of distinguishing between "no parameter passed at all" and "parameter passed, but given the default value"

Answer (score 1):

Some call it a *property*.

Comment: no, it's a function on an object, not a property of the object.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a standard name for functions which behave like this?

Getters and Setters.

**EDIT**:

I just realized that you want a single function to do this.  The technical term for this is a bad idea.  Unless your language provides properties, trying to rig up a single function to do this is very unreadable.

Comment: I mean, is there a name for a *single function* which does both?